# Acessing Hive Data on HAWQ/PXF with HCatalog

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hcatalog, hawq

I've configured **Hortonworks HDP** with **ambari** services, later I add **HAWQ** and **PXF**. Through some research i've seen that is possible to query data stored in Hive through **HCatalog** and since i already loaded the dataset to hive it would easy the work, but i am doing some benchmark, can someone tell me if the use of the **Hcatalog** affects **HAWQ** in terms of performance?

Comment: It will be much slower using tables stored in Hive than using native HAWQ tables.  Use the PXF feature to transfer data out of slow Hive and into fast HAWQ.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When HAWQ accesses PXF tables using HCatalog integration, it determines format of underlying table(and even partition) and uses profile, optimized for that particular format, so there should be no performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Oleksandr's point, when HAWQ queries hcatalog, even the Hive catalog data is stored only in memory and not on disk within HAWQ without any contention with native HAWQ tables. That said, external hcatalog queries wouldn't be as performant as native HAWQ queries.